# What to do with an invitation from a friend in UK whom I wish to visit during a short holiday there?

Tags: visas, uk

I have a friend in England ready to welcome me for a short holiday. Where or which office should he approach with his invitation for my visa application?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Are you trying to visit a friend who's a resident in UK and you want to know which visa to apply for?

Comment: @pnuts that's not a comment, that should be the answer.

Comment: @pnuts, that's fine what you wrote.

Comment: i don't ask for which kind of visa i need, i mean my friend can make for my the visa process in UK or any documentation plus the invitation letter from UK.

Answer (score 1):

None. Your friend doesn't apply for a visa for you, you do. This letter will be one piece of documentation you need, you will also need to prove ties to your country and so forth. For example, this is the site to check for if you are in [India](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/India/), this is [Saudi Arabia](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/saudiarabia/) and so on.

In general, in almost all cases it is you who apply for the visa. There are a few work visas where the employer applies but both for visits and immigration, the fundamental rule is the visitor/immigrant files with the optional help from some  entities in the target country.

Comment: OK i need to know much must be in my account when i apply for visiting visa (bank statements for the last six months) iam in Egypt.